# flutter do changes upon page gets pop

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I have Page1 and Page2.

Page 1 is my base page and I am doing `Navigator.push` for Page2. After finishing my logic in Page2, I will do `Navigator.pop()` to return back to Page1.

How will I know that Page1 has become the main page visible to user?

I have tried `ModalRoute.of(context).isCurrent` but I only want to know when Page2 has pop from Page1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `await` for the `Page1` to finish and pass some data is required from the `Page2` to make sure `Page2` has been popped from the Navigator stack.

On Page1

```
bool result = await Navigator.push(context,..);
```

On Page2

```
Navigator.pop(context,"some data");
```

Then your `result` will hold value "some data" if it's on the `Page1`.You can similarly pass a boolean or other required data and compare it to know if the `Page2`  has been popped.

Comment: Hi do you mean `Navigator.pop(context, "some data")`?

Comment: Yeah, I meant  `Navigator.pop(context, "some data")`, I'll update the same.

Answer (score 1):

Page2

```
//here value is dynamic so you can send any type of data here
    Navigator.pop("value");
```

Page1

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, Page2.routeName)
        .then((value) {
//here you will get value that you passed in Page2 of any type

});
```

Comment: Thanks, same result as the earlier answer

Comment: it is interesting snippet. In place where You have comment I can execute code from non-static method defined on `Page2`?